# assign attribute to attribute set

Tags: magento2, customer-attribute, setup-script

How to assign particular attribute set to newly created attribute?

My code is

```
    eavSetup->addAttribute(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
        'test_demo221',
        [

     //   'group' => 'Bag',
        'attribute_set_id' => 16,
            'type' => 'int',
            'backend' => '',
            'frontend' => '',
            'label' => 'Test Attribute',
            'input' => '',
            'class' => '',
            'source' => '',
            'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
            'visible' => true,
            'required' => false,
            'user_defined' => false,
            'default' => 0,
            'searchable' => false,
            'filterable' => false,
            'comparable' => false,
            'visible_on_front' => false,
            'used_in_product_listing' => true,
            'unique' => false,
            'apply_to' => ''
        ]
    );
```

It creates the attribute but appear in all attribute set. What should I have to do if I want to add to particular attribute set only?

Comment: Above code adding attribute to all attribute sets and not only to specified one. Please help me to do that.

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask). You can also [add a bounty](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question once you have enough [reputation](https://magento.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/135936)

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/135936)

Answer (score 2):

Hey if you using Magento 2 then

add below function in your custom helper class

```
public function addAttributeToAllAttributeSets($attributeCode,$attributeGroupCode) {

        $entityType = $this->eavTypeFactory->create()->loadByCode('catalog_product');

        $attribute = $this->attributeFactory->create()->loadByCode($entityType->getId(), $attributeCode);

        if (!$attribute->getId()) {
            return false;
        }

        /** @var \Magento\Eav\Model\ResourceModel\Entity\Attribute\Set\Collection $setCollection */
        $setCollection = $this->attributeSetFactory->create()->getCollection();
        $setCollection->addFieldToFilter('entity_type_id', $entityType->getId());

        /** @var Set $attributeSet */
        foreach ($setCollection as $attributeSet) {
            /** @var Group $group */
            $group = $this->attributeGroupFactory->create()->getCollection()
                    ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_group_code', ['eq' => $attributeGroupCode])
                    ->addFieldToFilter('attribute_set_id', ['eq' => $attributeSet->getId()])
                    ->getFirstItem();

            $groupId = $group->getId() ? : $attributeSet->getDefaultGroupId();

            // Assign:
            $this->attributeManagement->assign(
                    'catalog_product', $attributeSet->getId(), $groupId, $attributeCode, $attributeSet->getCollection()->count() * 10
            );
        }

        return true;
    }
```

and for this construct function to create objects will be

```
public function __construct(
            AttributeFactory $attributeFactory,
            SetFactory $attributeSetFactory,
            CatalogtransporterFactory $catalogTransporterFactory,
            GroupFactory $attributeGroupFactory,
            TypeFactory $typeFactory,
            AttributeManagement $attributeManagement,
            Context $context,
            \Magento\Eav\Setup\EavSetupFactory $eavSetupFactory,
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute $cattributeFactory,
            \Magento\Eav\Model\Config $eavConfig,
            \Magento\Eav\Model\AttributeRepository $attributeRepository,
            \Magento\Eav\Api\AttributeOptionManagementInterface $attributeOptionManagement,
            \Magento\Eav\Api\Data\AttributeOptionLabelInterface $attributeOptionLabel,
            \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Option $option
    ) {
        $this->attributeFactory = $attributeFactory;
        $this->attributeSetFactory = $attributeSetFactory;
        $this->catalogTransporterFactory = $catalogTransporterFactory;
        $this->eavTypeFactory = $typeFactory;
        $this->attributeGroupFactory = $attributeGroupFactory;
        $this->attributeManagement = $attributeManagement;
        $this->_eavSetupFactory = $eavSetupFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->eavConfig = $eavConfig;
        $this->_cattributeFactory = $cattributeFactory;
        $this->_attributeRepository = $attributeRepository;
        $this->_attributeOptionManagement = $attributeOptionManagement;
        $this->_option = $option;
        $this->_attributeOptionLabel = $attributeOptionLabel;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
```

And then call same function

```
 $helper = $this->_objectManager->create('\Companyname\Modulename\Helper\Data');
            $helper->addAttributeToAllAttributeSets('attribute_code','general');
```

Comment: The use imports would be helpfull

Answer (score 2):

Just change attribute_set_id with attribute_set. Like this:

```
eavSetup->addAttribute(
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,
    'test_demo221',
    [

 //   'group' => 'Bag',
    'attribute_set' => '<yourattributesetname>',
        'type' => 'int',
        'backend' => '',
        'frontend' => '',
        'label' => 'Test Attribute',
        'input' => '',
        'class' => '',
        'source' => '',
        'global' => \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Eav\Attribute::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'visible' => true,
        'required' => false,
        'user_defined' => false,
        'default' => 0,
        'searchable' => false,
        'filterable' => false,
        'comparable' => false,
        'visible_on_front' => false,
        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
        'unique' => false,
        'apply_to' => ''
    ]
);
```

Comment: providing 'attribute_set' => 'Default', does not work for me

Comment: Thanks. How can we add this single attribute to multiple attribute set ? 'attribute_set' => ['set1','set2'], this is not working.

Answer (score 1):

Simply change the below line

`'attribute_set_id' => 16,`

to

`'attribute_set' =>  'AttributeSetName',`

Now your attribute get assigned to above mentioned attribute name.

Comment: so, can we provide 'attribute_set' =>  'Default, to assign to default attribute set

Answer (score 0):

create and assign to custom attribute set :

```
$AttributeInterface->setAttributeCode($currentAttributeCode);
$AttributeInterface->setDefaultFrontendLabel($currentAttributeLabel); 
$AttributeInterface->setIsRequired(false);
$AttributeInterface->setIsUserDefined(true);
$AttributeInterface->setBackendType('varchar');
$AttributeInterface->setFrontendInput('text');
$AttributeInterface->setEntityTypeId($attributeSet['defaultAttributeSetId']);
$AttributeRepos->save($AttributeInterface);
$createdAttributeId=$AttributeInterface->getAttributeId();
$AttributeManage->assign('catalog_product',(int)$attributeSet['AttributeSetId'], (int)$groupId,$currentAttributeCode,++$attributeSetCounter);
```