# How do I assign an attribute to a group using the REST api?

Tags: magento2, rest-api

I know how to create a configurable product based off an existing attribute from [this tutorial on the dev docs](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/tutorials/configurable-product/config-product-intro.html), and I know how to create a new attribute [from this answer on another question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/257442/85484). When I create the new attribute, it shows as unassigned in my attribute set. From what I can tell, I need the new attribute assigned to a group before I can use it in the configurable/simple product payloads. What kind of request do I need to write to do this?

Basically, I want to do this using the REST api:
[image: example]

Comment: please check this link https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/141203/assign-attribute-to-attribute-set . I hope it will help you.

Comment: Unfortunately, `attribute_set` isn't a valid option for the attribute payload. Thank you though.

Comment: I found this answer worked for me https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41996794/magento2-rest-api-attribute-to-attribute-group